# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Form Input Validation Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

So, I am developing a theoretically simple enough questionnaire application with user accounts and I am trying to validate the user input. For example here I am trying to make the First name field Required. I have followed some tutorials and it should be simple but I must be missing something. When I check if my model state is valid to reload the page or post the data, I get an error message telling me that the fields are required even though I have provided a value for them. *I have removed some unimportant code parts for clarity.* What seems to be the problem here?

**CreateAdmin.cshtml**

```
@page
@model ResumePostingService.Pages.CRUD.CreateAdminModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Admin";
    Layout = "~/Pages/SharedPages/_Layout_Admin.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <h2>@Model.Messages</h2>
</div>

<h2>Add a new Admin Record</h2>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Admin.FirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="Admin.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Admin.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Admin_Pages/Admin_Index" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**CreateAdmin.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace ResumePostingService.Pages.CRUD
{
    public class CreateAdminModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ResumePostingService.Models.ResumePostingServiceDatabaseContext _context;

        public CreateAdminModel(ResumePostingService.Models.ResumePostingServiceDatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        readonly DataAccessClass objadmin = new DataAccessClass();

        [BindProperty]
        public Admin Admin { get; set; }

        public string Messages { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Admin Id") == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/SharedPages/Unauthorized");
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }

        public ActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                        .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

                return Page();
            }

            objadmin.AdAddAdmin(Admin);

            return RedirectToPage("/Admin_Pages/Admin_Index", new { actres = 4 });
        }
    }
}
```

**Admin.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ResumePostingService.Models
{
    public partial class Admin
    {
        public Admin()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        public int AdminId { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter the name")]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be longer than 20 characters and less than 2 characters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: "I get an error message telling me that the fields are required even though I have provided a value for them." Which fields will show this issue, the FirstName or the AdminId (Is it auto increase?)? I have created a sample to test your code (without the `objadmin.AdAddAdmin(Admin);`), if I provided a value for the FirstName, everything works well, the ModelState.IsValid is `true`. So, try to set a debugger in your code and check the ModelState.IsValid value, and check the `Admin` object, whether it contains the related value. Perhaps this issue occurs when insert the admin into the database.

Comment: @ZhiLv I was referring just to the FirstName field (I have more in the actual code). Hm it is strange, I commended out the ModelState check and the restrictions (required, min max length) work fine and an entry is created in the database as it should only if they are satisfied. Shouldn't the model state check determine whether the restrictions are met? Is it dangerous to not check the model state?

Comment: First, if commented out the ModelState check, it will use the client validation to check the restrictions, so, the restrictions work fine. Second, the ModelState is used to do the server side validation, if client side disable JavaScript (client side validation), we could use the ModelState to check whether the model is validated or not. So, it removes it, it might cause the validation not working (if the client side validation is disabled). Here is an article about [Model validation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0), you could check it.